# Android : Including LinearLayout issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to include LinearLayout  layout to my layout with `<include>` tag but i have some problem with it , I'm beginner in android

Here is my main layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.android.activity.MapActivity" >


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        **android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_menu"**
        class="com.android.fragment.MapFragment"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <include layout="buttom_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And it's my another layout that is included in main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/very_light_gray"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout //some code</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout //some code</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the `android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_menu` line , eclipse does not find any id with `bottom_menu` name , because it's including and it seems eclipse does not search included files , what is the solution?
I tried for override `id` with following code , but application occur run time error

```
<include 
        layout="buttom_menu"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_menu"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add @layout

```
<include layout="@layout/buttom_menu" />
```